# Проблема в pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, разработка-игр, telebot, while

Я хотел сделать свою игру в телеграм боте, проблема заключается в том что *(скрин №1, скрин №2)* код работает просто отлично, а когда переходишь в **TelegramBotApi** и пишешь туда всё то же самое, код перестаёт нормально функционировать *(скрин №3, скрин №4)*, присылая каждый раз одну и туже строчку, как переписать код что бы всё нормально и стабильно функционировало ?

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIqrX.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ayhD.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB0qy.png
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKlEP.png

Answer (score 1):

Ты застрял в цикле While. Тебе нужно разбить все на 2 функции и в первой написать сообщение, например количество хп, передать его во вторую через `next_step_handler` и тогда 2 функция будет ждать ответ пользователя.

```
msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Количество хп')
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, 2_step_funk)
```

Дальше ты столкнёшься с проблемой что хп у тебя общее на всех игроков. Соответственно тебе нужно либо подключать сюда базу данных, либо делать через классы, куда записывать как словарь ключом id пользователя а значением хп.

Совету все же БД, она стабильнее. С SQLite довольно легко разобраться и она реально открывает новые горизонты